# Is it possible to create a Shiny app and make it available on the Play and Apple Store as a regular app?

Tags: r, shiny

I created an application with the `shinyMobile` package and I would like to know if it is possible to make it available on the Play and Apple Store as a regular app.

My app:

```
library(shinyMobile)

if(interactive()){
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyMobile)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = f7Page(
      title = "Tab layout",
      f7TabLayout(
        tags$head(
          tags$script(
            "$(function(){
               $('#tapHold').on('taphold', function () {
                 app.dialog.alert('Tap hold fired!');
               });
             });
             "
          )
        ),
        panels = tagList(
          f7Panel(title = "Left Panel", side = "left", theme = "light", "Blabla", effect = "cover"),
          f7Panel(title = "Right Panel", side = "right", theme = "dark", "Blabla", effect = "cover")
        ),
        navbar = f7Navbar(
          title = "Tabs",
          hairline = FALSE,
          shadow = TRUE,
          leftPanel = TRUE,
          rightPanel = TRUE
        ),
        f7Tabs(
          animated = FALSE,
          swipeable = TRUE,
          f7Tab(
            tabName = "Tab1",
            icon = f7Icon("envelope"),
            active = TRUE,
            f7Shadow(
              intensity = 10,
              hover = TRUE,
              f7Card(
                title = "Card header",
                f7Stepper(
                  "obs1",
                  "Number of observations",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 500,
                  step = 100
                ),
                plotOutput("distPlot1"),
                footer = tagList(
                  f7Button(inputId = "tapHold", label = "My button"),
                  f7Badge("Badge", color = "green")
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          f7Tab(
            tabName = "Tab2",
            icon = f7Icon("today"),
            active = FALSE,
            f7Shadow(
              intensity = 10,
              hover = TRUE,
              f7Card(
                title = "Card header",
                f7Select(
                  inputId = "obs2",
                  label = "Distribution type:",
                  choices = c(
                    "Normal" = "norm",
                    "Uniform" = "unif",
                    "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                    "Exponential" = "exp"
                  )
                ),
                plotOutput("distPlot2"),
                footer = tagList(
                  f7Button(label = "My button", href = "https://www.google.com"),
                  f7Badge("Badge", color = "orange")
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          f7Tab(
            tabName = "Tab3",
            icon = f7Icon("cloud_upload"),
            active = FALSE,
            f7Shadow(
              intensity = 10,
              hover = TRUE,
              f7Card(
                title = "Card header",
                f7SmartSelect(
                  inputId = "variable",
                  label = "Variables to show:",
                  c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                    "Transmission" = "am",
                    "Gears" = "gear"),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = "cyl"
                ),
                tableOutput("data"),
                footer = tagList(
                  f7Button(label = "My button", href = "https://www.google.com"),
                  f7Badge("Badge", color = "green")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
        dist <- rnorm(input$obs1)
        hist(dist)
      })
      
      output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
        dist <- switch(
          input$obs2,
          norm = rnorm,
          unif = runif,
          lnorm = rlnorm,
          exp = rexp,
          rnorm
        )
        
        hist(dist(500))
      })
      
      output$data <- renderTable({
        mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
      }, rownames = TRUE)
    }
  )
}
```

I produce conventional shinyapps, but I would like to know if there is a way to make a shinMobile available on mobile platforms.

I even tried to do something, but nothing that came close to a satisfactory solution.

Comment: 1. You need to buy a shiny server or host the web app somewhere. 2. You need to write a local app shell for the web app, more like an H5 app. 3. Upload and follow the regulations of app stores.